# Likert Scale Bar chart

Tags: r, bar-chart, likert

df

## A tibble: 5 x 3

A        B        C
        
1 Agree    Agree    Disagree

2 Neutral  Disagree Agree

3 Agree    Neutral  Neutral

4 Disagree Agree    Agree

5 Agree    Neutral  Agree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQB6.png)

I want to create a bar chart like this in R. Would you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the likert package for R

https://cran.r-project.org/package=likert

https://github.com/jbryer/likert

If you also Google "likert package in R" you'll find a few useful tutorials on its use.